# Installing libssh on windows using vcpkg

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, vcpkg, libssh

I'm trying to install `libssh` on windows using `vcpkg` like they recommend [libssh download guid](https://www.libssh.org/get-it/).

but when I run `vcpkg install libssh` it starts downloading stuff and configures cmake but when it tries to build `pthreads` it fails and I receive the following error:

```
error: building pthreads:x86-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
error: Please ensure you're using the latest port files with `git pull` and `vcpkg update`.
Then check for known issues at:
    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+in%3Atitle+pthreads
You can submit a new issue at:
    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/new?template=report-package-build-failure.md&title=[pthreads]+Build+error
Include '[pthreads] Build error' in your bug report title, the following version information in your bug description, and attach any relevant failure logs from above.
    vcpkg-tool version: 2023-03-14-105f7f7e8a5ea10dfac9874ff9d1a6bacba5f454
    vcpkg-scripts version: bc671eb90 2023-03-23 (2 days ago)
```

this is the entire output:

```
vcpkg install libssh

warning: Starting with the September 2023 release, the default triplet for vcpkg libraries will change from x86-windows to the detected host triplet (x64-windows). To resolve this message, add --triplet x86-windows to keep the same behavior.
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
    libssh[core,crypto,mbedtls]:x86-windows -> 0.10.4+20221123#3
  * mbedtls[core,pthreads]:x86-windows -> 2.28.1
  * pthreads[core]:x86-windows -> 3.0.0#13
Additional packages (*) will be modified to complete this operation.
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x86-windows...
A suitable version of powershell-core was not found (required v7.2.8) Downloading portable powershell-core 7.2.8...
Downloading powershell-core...
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v7.2.8/PowerShell-7.2.8-win-x86.zip->D:\Windows Apps\vcpkg\downloads\PowerShell-7.2.8-win-x86.zip
Downloading https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v7.2.8/PowerShell-7.2.8-win-x86.zip
Extracting powershell-core...
Restored 0 package(s) from C:\Users\omerd\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives in 223.2 us. Use --debug to see more details.
Installing 1/3 pthreads:x86-windows...
Building pthreads[core]:x86-windows...
-- Downloading https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=cfhcable;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=pilotfiber;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=gigenet;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=versaweb;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=ayera;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=netactuate;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=phoenixnap;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=astuteinternet;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=freefr;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=netcologne;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=deac-riga;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=excellmedia;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=iweb;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=jaist;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=jztkft;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=managedway;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=nchc;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=netix;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=ufpr;https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w//files/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip/download?use_mirror=tenet -> pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip...
-- Cleaning sources at D:/Windows Apps/vcpkg/buildtrees/pthreads/src/49e541b66c-6b4ff17b62.clean. Use --editable to skip cleaning for the packages you specify.
-- Extracting source D:/Windows Apps/vcpkg/downloads/pthreads4w-code-v3.0.0.zip
-- Applying patch fix-arm-macro.patch
-- Applying patch fix-arm64-version_rc.patch
-- Applying patch use-md.patch
-- Applying patch fix-pthread_getname_np.patch
-- Applying patch fix-install.patch
-- Using source at D:/Windows Apps/vcpkg/buildtrees/pthreads/src/49e541b66c-6b4ff17b62.clean
-- Found external ninja('1.11.0').
-- Getting CMake variables for x86-windows
-- Building and installing x86-windows-dbg
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_build_process.cmake:134 (message):
    Command failed: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.35.32215/bin/Hostx64/x86/nmake.exe" /NOLOGO /G /U /F Makefile all install "INSTALLDIR=D:\\Windows Apps\\vcpkg\\packages\\pthreads_x86-windows\\debug" "DESTROOT=D:\\Windows Apps\\vcpkg\\packages\\pthreads_x86-windows\\debug"
    Working Directory: D:/Windows Apps/vcpkg/buildtrees/pthreads/x86-windows-dbg
    See logs for more information:
      D:\Windows Apps\vcpkg\buildtrees\pthreads\install-x86-windows-dbg-out.log
      D:\Windows Apps\vcpkg\buildtrees\pthreads\install-x86-windows-dbg-err.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_build_nmake.cmake:156 (vcpkg_execute_build_process)
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_install_nmake.cmake:52 (vcpkg_build_nmake)
  ports/pthreads/portfile.cmake:44 (vcpkg_install_nmake)
  scripts/ports.cmake:147 (include)


error: building pthreads:x86-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
error: Please ensure you're using the latest port files with `git pull` and `vcpkg update`.
Then check for known issues at:
    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+in%3Atitle+pthreads
You can submit a new issue at:
    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/new?template=report-package-build-failure.md&title=[pthreads]+Build+error
Include '[pthreads] Build error' in your bug report title, the following version information in your bug description, and attach any relevant failure logs from above.
    vcpkg-tool version: 2023-03-14-105f7f7e8a5ea10dfac9874ff9d1a6bacba5f454
    vcpkg-scripts version: bc671eb90 2023-03-23 (2 days ago)


Please use the prefilled template from D:\Windows Apps\vcpkg\installed\vcpkg\issue_body.md when reporting your issue.
```

D:\Windows Apps\vcpkg\buildtrees\pthreads\install-x86-windows-dbg-err.log :

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.35.32216.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.35.32216.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/Zi' with '/Z7'

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.35.32216.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.35.32216.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/Zi' with '/Z7'

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.35.32216.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.35.32216.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/Zi' with '/Z7'

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.35.32216.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.35.32216.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The system cannot find the path specified.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'if not exist D:\Windows Apps\vcpkg\packages\pthreads_x86-windows\debug\bin mkdir D:\Windows Apps\vcpkg\packages\pthreads_x86-windows\debug\bin' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

D:\Windows Apps\vcpkg\buildtrees\pthreads\install-x86-windows-dbg-out.log :

```
Included: common.mk
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\Hostx64\x86\nmake.exe" /E clean VC-debug
    if exist *.obj del *.obj
    if exist *.def del *.def
    if exist *.ilk del *.ilk
    if exist *.pdb del *.pdb
    if exist *.exp del *.exp
    if exist *.map del *.map
    if exist *.o del *.o
    if exist *.i del *.i
    if exist *.res del *.res
    if exist *_stamp del *_stamp
    cd tests && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\Hostx64\x86\nmake.exe" clean
    if exist *.dll erase *.dll
    if exist *.lib erase *.lib
    if exist _ptw32.h erase _ptw32.h
    if exist pthread.h erase pthread.h
    if exist semaphore.h erase semaphore.h
    if exist sched.h erase sched.h
    if exist *.e erase *.e
    if exist *.i erase *.i
    if exist *.obj erase *.obj
    if exist *.pdb erase *.pdb
    if exist *.o erase *.o
    if exist *.asm erase *.asm
    if exist *.exe erase *.exe
    if exist *.manifest erase *.manifest
    if exist *.pass erase *.pass
    if exist *.bench erase *.bench
    cl /errorReport:none /nologo /MDd /I. /DHAVE_CONFIG_H /W3 /Z7  /D__PTW32_BUILD_INLINED /D__PTW32_CLEANUP_C -c pthread.c
pthread.c
    rc /d__PTW32_ARCHAMD64 /d__PTW32_RC_MSC /d__PTW32_CLEANUP_C version.rc
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 10.0.10011.16384
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    cl /errorReport:none /nologo /LDd /Zi pthread.obj version.res /link /implib:pthreadVC3d.lib  /out:pthreadVC3d.dll
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/Zi' with '/Z7'
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/Zi' with '/Z7'
   Creating library pthreadVC3d.lib and object pthreadVC3d.exp
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\Hostx64\x86\nmake.exe" /E clean VCE-debug
    if exist *.obj del *.obj
    if exist *.def del *.def
    if exist *.ilk del *.ilk
    if exist *.pdb del *.pdb
    if exist *.exp del *.exp
    if exist *.map del *.map
    if exist *.o del *.o
    if exist *.i del *.i
    if exist *.res del *.res
    if exist *_stamp del *_stamp
    cd tests && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\Hostx64\x86\nmake.exe" clean
    if exist *.dll erase *.dll
    if exist *.lib erase *.lib
    if exist _ptw32.h erase _ptw32.h
    if exist pthread.h erase pthread.h
    if exist semaphore.h erase semaphore.h
    if exist sched.h erase sched.h
    if exist *.e erase *.e
    if exist *.i erase *.i
    if exist *.obj erase *.obj
    if exist *.pdb erase *.pdb
    if exist *.o erase *.o
    if exist *.asm erase *.asm
    if exist *.exe erase *.exe
    if exist *.manifest erase *.manifest
    if exist *.pass erase *.pass
    if exist *.bench erase *.bench
    cl /errorReport:none /nologo /MDd /EHs /TP /I. /DHAVE_CONFIG_H /W3 /Z7  /D__PTW32_BUILD_INLINED /D__PTW32_CLEANUP_CXX -c pthread.c
pthread.c
    rc /d__PTW32_ARCHAMD64 /d__PTW32_RC_MSC /d__PTW32_CLEANUP_CXX version.rc
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 10.0.10011.16384
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    cl /errorReport:none /nologo /LDd /Zi pthread.obj version.res /link /implib:pthreadVCE3d.lib  /out:pthreadVCE3d.dll
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/Zi' with '/Z7'
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/Zi' with '/Z7'
   Creating library pthreadVCE3d.lib and object pthreadVCE3d.exp
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\Hostx64\x86\nmake.exe" /E clean VSE-debug
    if exist *.obj del *.obj
    if exist *.def del *.def
    if exist *.ilk del *.ilk
    if exist *.pdb del *.pdb
    if exist *.exp del *.exp
    if exist *.map del *.map
    if exist *.o del *.o
    if exist *.i del *.i
    if exist *.res del *.res
    if exist *_stamp del *_stamp
    cd tests && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\Hostx64\x86\nmake.exe" clean
    if exist *.dll erase *.dll
    if exist *.lib erase *.lib
    if exist _ptw32.h erase _ptw32.h
    if exist pthread.h erase pthread.h
    if exist semaphore.h erase semaphore.h
    if exist sched.h erase sched.h
    if exist *.e erase *.e
    if exist *.i erase *.i
    if exist *.obj erase *.obj
    if exist *.pdb erase *.pdb
    if exist *.o erase *.o
    if exist *.asm erase *.asm
    if exist *.exe erase *.exe
    if exist *.manifest erase *.manifest
    if exist *.pass erase *.pass
    if exist *.bench erase *.bench
    cl /errorReport:none /nologo /MDd /I. /DHAVE_CONFIG_H /W3 /Z7  /D__PTW32_BUILD_INLINED /D__PTW32_CLEANUP_SEH -c pthread.c
pthread.c
    rc /d__PTW32_ARCHAMD64 /d__PTW32_RC_MSC /d__PTW32_CLEANUP_SEH version.rc
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 10.0.10011.16384
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    cl /errorReport:none /nologo /LDd /Zi pthread.obj version.res /link /implib:pthreadVSE3d.lib  /out:pthreadVSE3d.dll
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/Zi' with '/Z7'
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/Zi' with '/Z7'
   Creating library pthreadVSE3d.lib and object pthreadVSE3d.exp
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\Hostx64\x86\nmake.exe" /E clean
    if exist *.obj del *.obj
    if exist *.def del *.def
    if exist *.ilk del *.ilk
    if exist *.pdb del *.pdb
    if exist *.exp del *.exp
    if exist *.map del *.map
    if exist *.o del *.o
    if exist *.i del *.i
    if exist *.res del *.res
    if exist *_stamp del *_stamp
    cd tests && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\Hostx64\x86\nmake.exe" clean
    if exist *.dll erase *.dll
    if exist *.lib erase *.lib
    if exist _ptw32.h erase _ptw32.h
    if exist pthread.h erase pthread.h
    if exist semaphore.h erase semaphore.h
    if exist sched.h erase sched.h
    if exist *.e erase *.e
    if exist *.i erase *.i
    if exist *.obj erase *.obj
    if exist *.pdb erase *.pdb
    if exist *.o erase *.o
    if exist *.asm erase *.asm
    if exist *.exe erase *.exe
    if exist *.manifest erase *.manifest
    if exist *.pass erase *.pass
    if exist *.bench erase *.bench
    if not exist D:\Windows Apps\vcpkg\packages\pthreads_x86-windows\debug\bin mkdir D:\Windows Apps\vcpkg\packages\pthreads_x86-windows\debug\bin
```